# How do I set the X Axis to equal a predetermined range in excel using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have been able to create a graph using vb.net. The data is being displayed correctly however the X axis is incrementing 1, 2, 3... How do I specify a range for the X axis.

My code is:

```
            Dim chartPage As excel.Chart
            Dim xlCharts As excel.ChartObjects
            Dim myChart As excel.ChartObject
            Dim chartRange As excel.Range

            oSheet.Cells(2).columnwidth = 4.29
            oSheet.Cells(3).ColumnWidth = 5.71
            oSheet.Range("D1", "P1").ColumnWidth = 6.14
            oSheet.Cells(17).ColumnWidth = 9.29
            oSheet.Cells(18).ColumnWidth = 12
            oSheet.Cells(19).ColumnWidth = 7.86

            xlCharts = oSheet.ChartObjects
            myChart = xlCharts.Add(715, 30, 672, 360)
            chartPage = myChart.Chart
            chartRange = oSheet.Range("D3", "S" + CStr(RowCount))
            chartPage.SetSourceData(Source:=chartRange)
            chartPage.ChartType = excel.XlChartType.xlLine
```

Here is the spreadsheet that is being created:
[Spreadsheet and chart created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wi7yE.png)

Rather than the bottom axis of the chart being 1 threw 23 I need it to be the values in the Weeks column. (C3:C26)

Comment: Set the Minimum/MaximumScale properties on the Axis object: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.axis(object)